# Django: Is there an in_ lookup for querying model objects like there is for SQLAlchemy queries?

Tags: django-models, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

```
  userSelectionIDs = [pref.selectionID for pref in UserColumnSelectionPreference.objects.filter(user=reqUser).all()]
  selections = ColumnSelections.objects.filter(id.in_(userSelectionIDs)).filter(type=2).all()
```

Or, is there a better way for me to get that set of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
selections = ColumnSelections.objects.filter(id__in(userSelectionIDs)).filter(type=2).all()
```

See the [QuerySet API](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in).